# Warranty issues on replacement iphone

Tags: iphone, warranty

Hi i bought an iphone 6 plus from ebay recently and in the listing seller says it is a new phone that came from a iphone replacement and it has 12 months warranty since the day of purchase.

I then asked him how he was going to tranfer the warranty to my name and he replied:

"The warranty is with the phone for 12 months from date of purchase. It's not registered to an individual. So you would be able to take it to any Apple Store if you needed to."

I ask this community is this is normal or theres somekind of bull in here... The warranty is not transfered to me? The warranty goes in the name of who buys the product?!!

Answer (score 3):

It seems the seller has a decent understanding of things and what you wrote smells of no bull.

Apple warrants goods in the country of purchase (which sets obligations on the warrantee and the warrantor). Do keep in mind that the original purchase date of the phone sets the warranty. A replacement phone would have the remainder of the original one year warranty and a 90 day warranty from the date of the exchange - whichever is longer on it's own (the 90 days isn't stacked / it runs concurrently with any remaining warranty).

Possession means you can register the phone and seek all service as if you were the original purchaser with a few exceptions. You probably can't return it and you would need a notarized bill of sale and original receipt to do things like bypass activation lock.

You can check your phone warranty status at https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do

You can add AppleCare just as the original buyer could. You can seek any and all other warranty services as if you were the original buyer without needing any proof of ownership or purchase.

Comment: Except it's a replacement, doesn't that mean the warranty is the greater of one year from the original phones purchase date, or 90 days from the replacement date?

Comment: @Tyson Fair enough - edited that into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably check with Apple, but it used to be that the warranty, including AppleCare was based on the serial number.

From personal experience, we bought an iMac from a private seller, and when we registered the serial number to our Apple ID, AppleCare transferred to us with the time remaining.

The graphics card went bad during the AppleCare period and Apple replaced it without a charge.

Again, confirm with Apple first, as their policy for honoring warranties and AppleCare contracts may have changed since my experience. Also as bmike mentioned, there may be different contracts in different countries due to the statutes of that Jurisdiction.